# Linking to iframe pages

Tags: html, url, iframe, hyperlink

Is possible to link on sub page that is in iFrame?

So basically:

On www.domain.com/page I have just normal HTML page. And on that page I have iFrame where I get the content from www.anotherdomain.com.

Now on anotherdomain.com I have several subpages likes this:

```
www.anotherdomain.com/spage1
www.anotherdomain.com/spage2
etc.
```

Now the question is that is it possible to somehow link to one of these frames so that when user uses this link, it would go on one of these subpages. For example like this:
www.domain.com/page#spage2 
so that then the www.domain.com/page would show on iframe the content from the page www.anotherdomain.com/spage1

If I have understood correctly, this is not possible but I just need some confirmation on this :)

Sorry for bad explanation. Ask more info if you didn't understand what Im trying to explain.

Comment: You can just use proxy in the server side, if you want display many pages inside the **iframe** because in the client side you get the IFRAME as other domain

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking for correctly:

When a visitor goes to domain.com/page#spage2 you want them to see a url of: www.domain.com/page with the content of anotherdomain.com/spage2

If this is correct, I don't think you can do this with just HTML. You would need either regex in a .htaccess file or with PHP taking advantage of the $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] call.